# Object traversal function that goes over all attributes (including arrays w/o specified index) and returns last item in given path

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, lodash

I am trying to achieve a similar behavior to lodash's `_.get()` but with the difference that the function will be able to go over all/any of the arrays in the path instead of specifying the index in the path (ie. `'abc.xyz[0]`)

```js
    // Example 1
    
    const _object = {abc: {xyz: [{value: 1}, {value: 2}]}};
    
    console.log(accumulateValues(_object, 'abc.xyz.value');
    // Desired output: [{value: 1}, {value: 2}]
    
    // Example 2
    
    const _object = {abc: [{xyz: [{values: 1}]}]};
    
    console.log(accumulateValues(_object, 'abc.xyz.values');
    // Desired output: [1]
```

Comment: Why do you get `1` in the second instance and `{value: 1}` in the first?  It seems pretty inconsistent.

Comment: Don't have time to write a detailed answer rn, but you could use object-scan (npm package) with useArraySelector=false and rtn=value (disclaimer I'm the author)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly simple approach, if you want `[1, 2]` out of that might look like this:

```js
const query = (path, ps = path .split ('.')) => (obj) =>
  ps .reduce ((a, p) => a .flatMap (x => (x || {}) [p]) .filter (Boolean), [obj])

const _object = {abc: [{xyz: [{value: 1}, {value: 2}]}]}

console .log (query ('abc.xyz.value') (_object))
```

If you're looking for `[{value: 1}, {value: 2}]`, it probably wouldn't be much harder.  But if somehow, as the question seems to imply, you want either result, based upon how you wrap `'abc'`, then I don't really understand your requirements.

Here the brackets surrounding some nodes (such as `[xyz]`) don't add any value, since we simply assume there is an array all the way down, wrapping the initial value in one.  If you still wanted to supply them, we could remove them before processing:

```js
const query = (path, ps = path .replace (/[\[\]]/g, '') .split ('.')) => (obj) =>
// ...
```

We might want to improve this to take arrays at the root by checking whether the input was an array already before wrapping it in one.  I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, works flawlessly and also a brilliant and simple solution... Thanks for the suggestion to allow arrays at the root. I will look into it and update if/when implemented.

Comment: There's one more minor correction that probably should be applied.  `filter (Boolean)` is a really simple way to get rid of `undefined` values.  But it should probably be changed to either `filter (x => x != null)` or `filter (x => x !== undefined)`, because this will remove false-y values such as `0` and the empty string, which you might like to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). It is a bit more flexible, you can e.g. match unknown attributes with `*` or use a regex to match segments and much more (see documentation).

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.1.2/lib/index.min.js';

const f = (needle, obj) => objectScan([needle], {
  useArraySelector: false,
  rtn: 'value',
  reverse: false
})(obj);

const o1 = { abc: { xyz: [{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }] } };
const r1a = f('abc.xyz', o1);
console.log(r1a);
// => [ { value: 1 }, { value: 2 } ]

const r1b = f('abc.xyz.value', o1);
console.log(r1b);
// => [ 1, 2 ]

const o2 = { abc: [{ xyz: [{ values: 1 }] }] };
const r2a = f('abc.xyz.values', o2);
console.log(r2a);
// => [ 1 ]

const r2b = f('abc.*.values', o2);
console.log(r2b);
// => [ 1 ]
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)